# Is YouTube video fetching by API (WordPress plugin) indexed by Google?

Tags: seo, wordpress, video, api, youtube

I have a WordPress website. I displayed all videos thumbnail (25 videos) from a YouTube channel by `API (WP plugin). The video is in a popup and start playing when I click on this thumbnail. That means there are a HREF with this YouTube video URL. I want to know Is these all videos indexed by Google for my website?

[image]

One of my colleague tells me need to add JavaScript code for indexing by Google.

Comment: What does "indexed for my site" mean?   Is your goal for  these videos to appear in Google Video Search?    Google doesn't index videos as part of normal web search.

Comment: Stephen Ostermiller@, Yes, I want to these videos to appear in Google Video Search. You said, "Google doesn't index videos as part of normal web search". So, how can it possible? Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to say that the video index is separate from the web text index.  Similar to how the image index is separate.  I don't have any experience with getting videos listed in Google video search.  Somebody else here should be able to help you.